# Universal app supporting portrait and Portrait upside down, but rotation not happening on iPhone - UPDATED

Tags: ios

My app is a `universal application` that supports portrait and portrait upside down orientations.

My app uses a `UITabBarController` that has `UINavigationControllers` for 3 `UITabBarItems`.

To support of of these, i have done the following things:

1) added `"supported Interface Orientations"` key accordingly for both devices
2) added the following code in app delegate and all other view controllers

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Everything is going as expected in iPad, but on iPhone, only some of my views (not all) do not respond to change in Orientation..!! Why is this happening??

Comment: are you using a navigation controller for iPhone?

Comment: i am using a tabbar controller that has navigation controllers as tabbar items..

Answer (score 0):

You should check that all of your view controllers have the rotation defined, and then you should add this to them:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: the method you are suggesting is deprecated in iOS 6. And all my views return YES for rotation. Everything works fine on iPad, the problem is on iPhone only!

Comment: Are you using a Tab Bar controller or a Navigation controller?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but yes.. i am using both navigation controller and tabbarcontroller

Comment: actually, i have a tabbar controller that contains 3 navigation controllers as tab bar items..

Comment: Ok, you should subclass them (as I wrote in my other answer) in order to add the upside-down rotation feature.

Comment: but it is able to rotate in iPad without subclassing.. why is it not rotating on iPhone??

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2244/_index.html "By default, view controllers on iOS 6 support all orientations except portrait upside-down"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a navigation controller, you should create a subclass .i.e. "MyNavController" with the instructions to rotate in its implementation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

and then use it:

```
MyNavController *navo = [[MyNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myRootController];
```

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know upside down in portrait mode for the IPhone is not allowed, cause when a user receives a phonecall, the app is on hold and he has the phone upside down. Thats why apple does not want that.